# C# Console Application output to get or show files under a directory folder and its subfolders then save it in a database for file monitoring purpose

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, monitoring

Need help! I am new to programming and I really need help with C# and SQL for school purpose.

So I want to create a Console Application that gets files under a directory folder and its subfolder.
For example:
C:\Windows\Web

Then let's say I want to get the directory, file name, and last modified date of the files. To show them in the Console Application.

So the output in the Console Application should look like this:

C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Theme1 : Desktop.jpg : 07/12/2019 5:12:45 pm
C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Theme2 : img12.jpg : 07/12/2019 5:09:54 pm
C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Theme2 : img7.jpg : 07/12/2019 5:09:54 pm
C:\Windows\Web\Screen : img100.jpg : 07/12/2019 5:08:05 pm
C:\Windows\Web\Screen : img101.jpg : 07/12/2019 5:08:05 pm
C:\Windows\Web\4K\Wallpaper\Windows : img0_3840x2160.jpg : 07/12/2019 5:09:54 pm
C:\Windows\Web\4K\Wallpaper\Windows : img0_768x1024.jpg : 07/12/2019 5:09:54 pm
C:\Windows\Web\4K\Wallpaper\Windows : img0_768x1366.jpg : 07/12/2019 5:09:54 pm

And then I want to save this output in a database named "FileMonitoring" for file monitoring.

Please help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow michael. please check out [tour] and learn [ask]. you could watch directory content changes using [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed?view=net-6.0). you could then write data to database either using (but not limited to) ADO.Net or EntityFramework. please show us what you have tried and tell us if you got stuck on problems.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication27
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string folder = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + @"\Desktop";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach(string file in files)
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
                string fld = info.DirectoryName;
                string date = info.LastWriteTime.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" : ", new string[] { fld, info.Name, date}));
                
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I did this and it worked. My problem now is how do I save the output of this to a database for file monitoring?

Comment: If you want one line in database for file just put the database where the Writeline occurs.  If you want only one entry into database put results into a stringbuilder or StringWriter.